# Does this flowchart look right?

Tags: arrays, while-loop, flowchart

The flowchart I'm making doesn't look right. I've looked in my textbook for examples, but they don't seem to apply to this particular assignment. The pseudocode is right, because the Java is right, but the flowchart just looks wrong.

In this assignment the program is to display an array of items (iPod, Xbox, etc.) by using an array. The program is to ask the user which items they would like to order. The user is to enter the item. The program displays "In Stock". Then the program replaces the item from the array with an empty string. The program asks the user if they would like to make another order. If the user enters in the same item, the message "Out of Stock" is displayed.If the user enters another item, the same process repeats. (While loop) Entering the the word "No" ends the program.

You can see all this in the pseudocode, I just thought writing it all out might be easier. (Or not, maybe it just took extra work reading it.)

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm no flowchart guru, but I see that you have the 2nd WHILE as a conditional diamond with the loop completely under it. How does it ever escape that loop? The flow should always come into the top of the diamond, with the exit options on either side. This means that the first WHILE is wrong too.

Also, the third WHILE only has a single exit. And the same for the IF underneath it.

For all of these test/condition diamonds the flow should come in the top and exit either side.

Comment: Yeah, the first and second while look good to me. It has a true and false. But yes, the rest of it looks like a mess. I wrote it that way because the code is written that way. And I know the code is right because I compiled it on jgrasp. But like I said, the flowchart it messed up. I'm really not sure how to fix it :P

Comment: Okay, so I made some obvious changes. I don't think anyone's reading this thread anymore so I might post a new one with the updated flow chart, but here's the link! I'm still not sure if it looks right, but I think it looks much better :)

http://wishestono.deviantart.com/art/FinalAssignment-Final-Assignment-1-415966184?ga_submit_new=10%253A1385431592

Comment: Better, but you still have diamonds with the input coming in the side. I think this is wrong.
Also, you should try to have the END terminator at the bottom. Some of this may seem bothersome, but making a clear simple diagram is where you obtain the benefits of flowcharting. Note that you shouldn't flowchart your code, but you should flowchart first, to think through the problem, then code it.